# Lombok inner collection initialization

Tags: java, lombok

I use Lombok @Value annotation. Is it possible to somehow ensure, that inner collections will never be null?

Example:

```
package com.testapp;

import lombok.Value;
import lombok.experimental.Wither;

import java.util.List;

@Value
@Wither
public final class ClassWithList {

    private final List<String> list;

    public void printList() {
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

This will throw a `NullPointerException` if `list` is null. My current strategy was to never allow to happen, that an inner collection may be null, it was sanitized in constructor (setter,  builder...) . However in this case is the constructor automatically generated by Lombok. Is there any way, how to ensure that the `list` property will always be initialized at least to an empty collection or do I have to start writing the tedious null checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotation **@lombok.NonNull** does the trick:

```
@NonNull    
private final List<String> list;
```

This generates the following code in constructor and setter:

```
if (list == null)
  throw new NullPointerException("list is marked @NonNull but is null");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can override the constructor if there is a chance that the list you are passing in is null

```
public ClassWithList(List<String> aList) {
  this.list = aList == null ? new ArrayList<>() : aList;
}
```

From Project Lombok (emphasis mine): [Value](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value.html)

> @Value is shorthand for: final @ToString @EqualsAndHashCode **@AllArgsConstructor** @FieldDefaults(makeFinal = true, level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE) @Getter, except that explicitly including an **implementation of any of the relevant methods simply means that part won't be generated** and no warning will be emitted

Comment: For some reason I thought that it is not possible to declare methods, that are generated by Lombok.